# While loop being inefficient and not working

Tags: c++, struct, while-loop

Ok, well, I'm writing a program for a store (just a project to learn c++) and I'm having a problem. The white loop doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to, the program just goes through it.

I have a function:

```
int decimali_float (pole &artikli){
    int num = artikli.cena;
    int count = 0;
    num = abs(num);
    num = num - (int)num;
    while(num >= 0.0000001){
        num *= 10;
        count++;
        num -= (int)num;
    }
    return count;
}
```

And my struct is this :

```
struct pole{
    int sifra;             
    string opis;            
    float cena;          
    int vlez_kol;          
    int izlez_kol;        
    float dan_stapka;     
    float iznos;          
    int datum;          
};
```

And I've got an array declared for the struct:

```
pole artikli[100];
```

And here's my code where the while loop gets skipped.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    while(!(cin >> artikli[i].cena) || decimali_float(artikli[i]) > 2){
        cout << "Error, try again." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
 }
```

Where is my mistake?

`decimali_float` is a function to count the decimals of a number.

the element `cena` of the struct means `price` in English.

`pole artikli[100]` is the amount of elements(articles) in the struct

Comment: You haven't explained at all what your program (or any of its components) are supposed to do, so how are we expected to evaluate it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Edited please check it again :)

Comment: The while loop condition might get wrong somewhere. It may be due to the floating point precision. take double and then compare ! It may be due to the fact that you are comparing an int to a double number as compiler is probably treating that 0.0000001 as a double and hence the condition fails somewhere !

Comment: The number of digits can be found by `floor(log10(number)) + 1`, so long as number is not zero.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's not what I need. I need to check the decimals a number contains (example 2.523 contains 3 decimals .523).

Comment: @KaustavRay I have to use float (that's what the project requires, forced to). But I don't think that's the problem, because it doesn't work with double either.

Comment: The num variable you are using in the function 'decimali_float' can be taken as double or there is also some restrictions there ?

Comment: `num` has type `int`, so `num - (int)num` is 0, and the loop never executes.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks, I missed that one (due to many edits), it seems to "work" now, but for example, if the user inputs a number with more than 2 decimals, he gets an error and the second time he inputs a correct number, it still says incorrect, just keeps saying incorrect over and over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it only me, or `num` is an integer value which is explicitly set to value equal or below 0:

```
int num = artikli.cena;
num = abs(num);
num = num - (int)num;
```

Obviously it will always be less than whatever non-zero constant it is compared too and the while loop will get skipped.

**Update**

It appears that the main question was already addressed in comments. As for the follow-up question, instead of counting decimal places one may simply check, whether there is a residue from subtracting an adjusted "cena" from the original one (assuming `cena` is positive for now):

```
double cena1 = cena * 100;
if ((cena1 - floor(cena1)) > 0.000001)
    // error condition here
```

Comment: Yes, that was already posted by @Peter Becker in the comments, and it fixed the loop problem, but now if the user enters an incorrect value the first time, it will keep saying invalid whether he correct value or not all the time.

Comment: The mistake is to do this with the loop.

Comment: I found the solution actually, I changed the `while(num >= 0.1)` and it works perfectly now. Thanks for your effort and time :)